# Send POST data to iframe and host page

Tags: php, html

I am have a problem with Sending data from a Form to my `iframe` page.
I have a host page that is called from the Form and the Form is using the POST method this works. I am then trying to send that same POST data with in a `iframe`.

```
<iframe src="dirread.php?var=<?php echo urlencode($_POST['filename']);?>"  width="300px" height="700px" scrolling="yes">
```

So this works for one but I want to send two Lots

```
 <iframe src="dirread.php?var=<?php echo urlencode($_POST['filename'],$_POST['site'] );?>"  width="300px" height="700px" scrolling="yes">
```

What is the correct syntax please?

Comment: You cant send post parameters from url

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="iframe.php" target="my-iframe" method="post">
   
  <label for="text">Some text:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
   
  <input type="submit" value="post">
   
</form>
  
<iframe name="my-iframe" src="iframe.php"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the POST-Parameters as GET-Parameters to the iframe. To send 2 Variables you have to use:

```
<iframe src="dirread.php?var=<?php echo urlencode($_POST['filename']); ?>&var2=<?php echo urlencode($_POST['site'] );?>"  width="300px" height="700px" scrolling="yes">
```

There is no way to send POST Data inside an iframe.